# Expected and Actual not displayed in the console log - Groovy Spock

Tags: java, groovy, spock

When I use testResponse.code == 401 I can see the "Expected" and "Actual" from the console log. But when I use checkResponseCode(testResponse, 401) I get the following:

```
 Condition not satisfied:

checkResponseCode(testResponse, 401)
|         |
false     testpackage.project1.hs.unittestspack.utils.TestClass@17d88132
```

How do I fix checkResponseCode() method so that it produces expected and actual? Here's the implementation for checkResponseCode():

```
 static def checkResponseCode(resp, code) {
     resp.code == code
}
```

Here's the log I want to achieve:

```
Condition not satisfied:

testResponse.code == 401
|                |    |
|                500  false
testpackage.project1.hs.unittestspack.utils.TestClass@5b367418

Expected :401

Actual   :500

 <Click to see difference>
```

Comment: put an `assert` before the `respo.code==code`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could assert the condition in your helper method:

```
static void checkResponseCode( resp, code ) {
    assert resp.code == code
}
```

Comment: just use `void` instead of `def` and you won't need the explicit return.

Comment: Make the method void, and you won't have to return true: http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.1/all_in_one.html#_helper_methods